# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base tableor view not found:1146 Table 'tienda.productos' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-migrations

I have tried to change the static `$rules`, but then the controller code no longer works for me. I have also tried to delete it, but I did not insert records into the table. So it allows because I get another error due to the lack of static rules.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]:Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tienda.productos' doesn't exist
> (SQL: insert into 'productos'('nombre','Describcion','Clasificación')

**Producto.php**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    static $rules = [
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'Describcion' => 'required',
        'Clasificación' => 'required',
    ];

    protected $filliable = ['nombre', 'Describcion', 'Clasificación'];
}
```

**Migration**

```
class Productos extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('producto', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('Describcion');
            $table->text('Clasificación');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

But I need the static `$rules` for the controller because I can't remove it. So below is the controller code, and you can see that I am using the static `$rules`.

**ProductoController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        
use App\Models\Producto;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    
class ProductoController extends Controller
{
```

Here is the `$rules` variable.

```
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            request()->validate(Producto::$rules);
    
            $producto = Producto::create($request->all());
    
            return redirect()->route('productos.index')
                ->with('success', 'Producto created successfully.');
                return redirect()->route('productos.index2')
                ->with('success', 'Producto created successfully.');
        }
```

Here is the `$rules` variable.

```
        public function update(Request $request, Producto $producto)
        {
            request()->validate(Producto::$rules);
    
            $producto->update($request->all());
    
            return redirect()->route('productos.index')
                ->with('success', 'Producto updated successfully');
        }
```

I would greatly appreciate your help, and I will respond as quickly as possible and sorry for the written text; I don't speak or write English very well.

Comment: Whats the table's name on the database;?

Comment: the table in the database is productos and excuise me for taking so long to reply

Comment: did you create the migration of Product model and run the artisan migrate command? can you post this file?

Comment: I tried to publish it but the program wouldn't let me, can I paste it here in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

According to laravel documentation table name should be plural of model name.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

if you want to give custom table name for model you can do by following code in model.

protected $table = 'producto';